# It's normal that PUSH events occurs ever twice in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, lifecycle

I'm trying to understand well the Flutter Lifecycle and I'm not sure that is normal that events like PUSH a view occurs twice. 
I'm searching for a event that occurs one time only when the view is showed. For example:
ViewA is showed eventImSearchingOn occurs one only time.
ViewA open ViewB, ViewA is deactivate.
ViewB go back to ViewA and eventImSearchingOn occurs one only time.

The log of the code that I've tried:

```
InitState SplashScreenUI
ChangeDependencies SplashScreenUI
PUSH SplashScreenUI
InitState SplashScreenUI
ChangeDependencies SplashScreenUI
PUSH SplashScreenUI
```

Main Class

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreProvider<AppState>(
      store: widget.store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        ...
        ....
        initialRoute: '/SplashScreen',
        home: SplashScreenUI(),
        navigatorKey: Keys.navKey,
        navigatorObservers: [Keys.routeObserver],
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/Home': (BuildContext context) => HomePageUI(),
          '/Login': (BuildContext context) => LoginPageUI(),
          '/Routine': (BuildContext context) => RoutineUI(),
          '/Notifications': (BuildContext context) => NotificationsUI(),
          '/Chat': (BuildContext context) => ChatUI(),
          '/Profile': (BuildContext context) => ProfileUI(),
          '/ProfileForm': (BuildContext context) => ProfileFormUI(),
          '/Interview': (BuildContext context) => InterviewUI(),
          '/BodyCheck': (BuildContext context) => BodyCheckUI(),
          '/SplashScreen': (BuildContext context) => SplashScreenUI(),
```

SplashScreen Class

```
class _SplashScreenUIState extends State<SplashScreenUI>  with RouteAware{

  _SplashScreenUIState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("InitState SplashScreenUI");
    super.initState();
    store.dispatch(CheckLogIn());
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print("ChangeDependencies SplashScreenUI");
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    Keys.routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context));
  }

  @override
  void deactivate() {
    print("Deactivate SplashScreenUI");
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Dispose SplashScreenUI");
    Keys.routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPush() {
    print("PUSH SplashScreenUI");    
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print("POP SplashScreenUI");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,
the problem are there:

```
initialRoute: '/SplashScreen',
home: SplashScreenUI(),
```

This double declaration cause that SplashScreen are called twice.
Change to this, solve the problem.

```
home: SplashScreenUI(),
```